# SSL certificate SHA2 in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl-certificate

I am using SSL SHA2 in ASP.Net MVC system, but browsers see the certificate as SHA1. So, I logged in to GoDaddy to be sure for the SSL certificate type, and I read this beside the type SHA2:

> Unless you have interoperability issues due to legacy code that requires you to use SHA-1, it's a best practice to use SHA-2 encryption.

FYI: I am using ASP.Net MVC4, .NET framework 4.5, C#,
and I am enforcing the use of HTTPS by attribute `[RequireHttps]`.

I just set up the SSL certificate for my web host. Both are from the same GoDaddy server and specify the domain and write the attribute.
Should I do anything else in my code? Is this related to the CSR?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the certificate, and it sounds unrelated to C#, ASP.NET, or MVC.

Comment: It’s not depend on your code. You have to create SHA2 CSR that discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802868/how-can-i-make-sha2-csr-file-for-iis-web-site-on-windows-2012r2)