# How can I make SHA2 CSR file for IIS web site on windows 2012R2?

Tags: ssl, sha1, windows-server-2012-r2

I need  SSL cert for a web site but CA did not accept my CSR and told me, that is SHA1 algorithm and you should send SHA2 based CSR file.
How can I create SHA2 CSR file for IIS web site on windows 2012R2 ?

Comment: This article helped me: [How to create SHA2 CSR on windows server](https://web.archive.org/web/20220124092445/http://day.ir/en-us/articles/ssl/create-csr-sha2-algorithm) (published 2015/12/22 by Amir Javidan)